# Button Active focus shadow default problem

Tags: html, css, button

The top of the button seems to have a default shadow when clicked you can see in the Codepen example the gold border gets darker around the top rim - how do I remove this behaviour?

[Example](https://codepen.io/jonathan-werrey-easterbrook/pen/madpwa)

```
.button {
   cursor:pointer;
   height: 3rem;
   width:10rem;
   margin:15px;
   font-size:2em;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(89,89,89,1) 9%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 20%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 34%,rgba(71,71,71,1) 34%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 45%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 54%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
   text-decoration:none;
   border-radius:10rem;
   border-color:#fcbd3f ;
   border-width: 1.5px;
   color:#d4d6d8 ;
   box-shadow: 0px 17px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   outline: none;

   &:active{
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 10px -10px;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 51%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 70%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 70%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 82%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 82%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 82%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 82%,rgba(66,66,66,1) 84%,rgba(84,84,84,1) 91%,rgba(109,109,109,1) 92%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 98%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
   } 

   &:hover{
      color: white;
      outline: none;
   }
}

button:active{
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 10px -10px;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 16%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 51%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 70%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 70%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 82%,rgba(43,43,43,1) 82%,rgba(56,56,56,1) 82%,rgba(44,44,44,1) 82%,rgba(66,66,66,1) 84%,rgba(84,84,84,1) 91%,rgba(109,109,109,1) 92%,rgba(102,102,102,1) 98%,rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%,rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code fixes your problem:

```
.button:active {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-style: solid;
}
```

EDIT: or please check working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZOvNW)

Answer (score 1):

The border you have on the button is the default border. Hou only adjusted the width and the color, not the style.

Therefore it's common practise to define a button like so:
`border: 1.5px solid #fcbd3f;`

Where solid is the style of the border.